# Access to admin area without write permission

Tags: jira

Is it possible to grant access to jira-user with abilty to read all administration area (user, groups, permission scheme), but disable write permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can have JIRA Administrators (which have less permission than a JIRA System Administrator). More details [here](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Global+Permissions#ManagingGlobalPermissions-sysadmin).